# non www to www with https sub domain issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I'm using below rules but having issues with sub domains as http://sub.example.com is redirecting to https://sub.example.com/sub instead of https://sub.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect non-www to (ssl) www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Redirect non-SSL to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: Edited my question including the desired result/redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect non-www to (ssl) www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-SSL to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```